# Rendering line art with constant screen width

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, glsles

I have a line art texture applied to an object in 3D space. The default behavior is for the object and the texture to receive perspective scaling based on the perspective model view projection matrix. Is there any established technique to keep the positioning and scaling of the 3D object, while keeping the line width constant relative to the screen? The desired effect is as though a pen (fixed screen width) were used to trace a path on the 3D object.

Would something like SDF-based font rendering help?

Or maybe some kind of projective texture mapping?

Or render the object and texture to a buffer and expand the lines using edge detection?

Unfortunately, I'm using OGL ES 2, so I can't use a geom shader or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with is inspired by procedural SDF generation, like @Felipe suggested, combined with Chris Green's *Improved Alpha-Tested Magnification for Vector Textures and Special Effects*.

Basically I hand draw shapes into textures using pure red, green, and blue. Then I render the scene using those textures, and generate an SDF on the fly in a second render pass. The SDF generation uses Green's algorithm with a small spread to improve performance. The SDF is then passed to a final render pass that thresholds and antialiases the SDF per Green's approach, using `fwidth` to maintain a constant line weight regardless of the distance of the object to the camera.

Since the original question was just for the approach/concept, I'm not posting an example at the moment. But I'll see if I can put together a shadertoy sometime soon.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the texture procedurally in a fragment shader and use the size of a pixel for interpolations. 
See:
[FabriceNeyret's blog](https://shadertoyunofficial.wordpress.com/2019/01/02/programming-tricks-in-shadertoy-glsl/)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I need a manually drawn texture, not a procedurally generated one.